# .in Domains for less then $2

Tags: web-hosting, domains, email

Can anyone suggest me .in domains for less then $2 per year. It would be nice to have some type of email hosting with it.

I am looking to setup some domain forwarding and tinyURL like site, So it would be nice to get some with least possible investment for now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Flagging to close. Asking where to register at a particular(and *optimistically* low) price point is getting a little too specific.

Comment: You're expecting a domain name at a reliable host for the price of a beer? Dream on.

Comment: $2? Seriously? Did you miss off a `0`? Or maybe two? At the end of the day you get what you pay for. You *might* be able to get hosting for $2 (although I sort of doubt it) but for the love of God, *don't*...

Comment: My Request was only for the domain name. it could be under discount for first year. I did found it.  I in fact used ResellerClub and setup one for myself. http://www.tintorch.com/ here.